# @Validated + javax annotations not working for controller method parameters

Tags: spring, validation, parameters

I have a Restcontroller in a Spring project. And I have to validate its method's parameter.
Mainly Spring @Validated annotation on class + javax validation annotations are proposed to be a good practice working examples.
But it failed: Spring just ignores this validation: ConstraintViolationException supposed to be thrown is probably smoking somewhere outside and lets other exceptions do the dirty work following the code.

```java
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/reducedPageNumbers")
@Validated
@Tag(
        name = "Page number reducer controller",
        description = "This controller is responsible for the reduction of a given range of page numbers for printer"
)
public class PageReducerController {

    private final PageReducerService service;

    @Operation(
            method = "GET",
            summary = "Finding a user by ID",
            responses = {
                    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Successful Request"),
                    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Bad Request. " +
                            "All page numbers must be integers, separated by comas", content = {
                            @Content(
                                    mediaType = "application/json",
                                    array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorContainer.class)))
                    }),
                    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Unexpected Internal Server Error", content =
                            @Content)
            },
            description = "This method transforms a list of page numbers in one String line, separated by ',' " +
                    "into ascending reduced format of a String line for printer. " +
                    "E.g.: \"1,3,32,5,11,7,6,19,2,21,4,8,22,23\" -> \"1-8,11,19,21-23,32\". " +
                    "And returns a ReducerResponse object with both initial String input line 'original' " +
                    "and reduced String line 'reduced'"
    )
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<ReducerResponse> show(@NotNull @NotBlank String rawPageNumbers) {

        ReducerResponse response = service.reduce(rawPageNumbers);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

What can be a problem here?

Tried to validate a method parameter through @Validated + javax validation annotations. Expected: ConstraintViolationException. Actually resulted: validation totally ignored.

I also made sure I use spring validation starter, hibernate-validator 6.0.0 and configured MethodValidationPostProcessor as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class ValidationConfig {

    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor getMethodValidationPostProcessor(){
        MethodValidationPostProcessor processor = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
        processor.setValidator(this.validator());
        return processor;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator(){
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }
}
```

My Pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>by.smirnov</groupId>
    <artifactId>pagenumberreducer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <name>pagenumberreducer</name>
    <description>Page number reducer test project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <springdoc.version>1.6.14</springdoc.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springdoc.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springdoc.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Are you using Spring Framework 6 / Spring Boot 3? If so, you need to replace "javax" with "jakarta". Spring Framework 6 [has fully transitioned to Jakarta EE 9](https://spring.io/blog/2021/09/02/a-java-17-and-jakarta-ee-9-baseline-for-spring-framework-6) which means it no longer supports the old javax based namespaces.

Comment: Also if you are using Spring Boot (the keyword "starter" suggests you do :)), you shouldn't explicitly specify a version number for your Maven / Gradle dependencies that are managed by Spring Boot dependency management (including hibernate-validator), so that Spring Boot dependency mangement picks the versions that play nice with each other.

Could you show us your `pom.xml` / `build.gradle` (whichever you are using)?

Comment: No, Boot 2.7.8 & Spring 5. Yeah, I remebmer this Jakarta matter with Spring 6 & Boot 3, but it's not this case

Comment: Amended question with pom.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem using your POM and a stripped down version of your controller, but validation actually works.

Can you provide a complete minimal demo project on GitHub?

Comment: Also two suggestions (not immediately relevant to your problem, just general advice):
- With Spring Boot you shouldn't specify version numbers in your POM for [dependencies that are managed by the Spring Boot plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.8/reference/html/dependency-versions.html). In your case, hibernate-validator and validation-api.
- Please edit your question your code example in the question to not include irrelevant details, especially those elaborate Swagger annotations. More focus means better chances for helpful answers :)

Comment: Also, you should replace the `javax.validation:validation-api` dependency with `jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api`. The former is effectively deprecated. Don't wory, jakarta-validation-api 2.0 still uses the legacy javax package namespace and is compatible with Spring Framework 5.

Comment: And as a final hint, your `ValidationConfig` should not be needed because Spring Boot autoconfigures all that when hibernate-validator is present in the classpath.

Comment: Thanks, sorry, I tried all this out You've gracely recommended, but it's still working as the validation was absent there. Here's is the full project: https://github.com/AntonioBuenos/page-number-reducer

Comment: Well, funny story: I ran your app (mvn spring-boot:run) and got:


`curl http://localhost:8080/reducedPageNumers`

=> `not valid due to validation error: show.rawPageNumbers: must not be null, show.rawPageNumbers: must not be blank`.

Looks fine to me. Maybe try cleaning your Maven cache etc. and do a clean rebuild?

Comment: Yeah, strange things, did clean install plural times :-/

Comment: Hm. Sorry to say I'm out of ideas then. Your code seems to work.

Comment: Thanx a lot anyway, at least I know now the code is workable and smth else wrong with my environment

Comment: It started to work properly on Boot 3 with Jakarta 3.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem with Spring Boot 2.7.5 and Jakarta 3.0.2. After I tried removing (and then adding) jakarta.validation-api, adding javax.validation and all suggestions I found on other posts, the solution was in the comments of this question: remove the version number of my spring boot dependencies (in my case, hibernate-validator version number) and then it worked.

My pom now has this validation dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Hope this helps.